# error with python-minimal while patching server

Tags: apt, upgrade, python

I'm having some trouble patching one of my Ubuntu (16.04.3) servers. Its running a test installation of Archivematica.

There's basically a python-minimal fault and i haven't yet found an article to help resolve this.

While still searching i thought i'd just leave the question in case someone has a quick answer.

here is the output from the console. is anyone able to provide some advice?

```
root@archivesrv:/# apt upgrade -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed

  linux-headers-4.4.0-116 linux-headers-4.4.0-116-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-116-generic

The following packages will be upgraded:
  cpp-5 g++-5 gcc-5 gcc-5-base libasan2 libatomic1 libaudit-common
  libaudit1 libblkid1 libcc1-0 libcilkrts5 libcups2 libcupsimage2
  libfdisk1 libgcc-5-dev libgfortran3 libgomp1 libitm1 liblsan0
  libmount1 libmpx0 libnuma1 libobjc4 libpulse0 libpython-all-dev
  libpython-dev libpython-stdlib libquadmath0 libsmartcols1
  libstdc++-5-dev libstdc++6 libtsan0 libubsan0 libuuid1
  linux-firmware linux-generic linux-headers-generic
  linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev ntp open-vm-tools postfix python

43 to upgrade, 4 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/149 MB of archives.
After this operation, 301 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
Extract templates from packages: 100%

Preconfiguring packages ...
Setting up python-minimal (2.7.12-1~16.04) ...
dpkg: error processing package python-minimal (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-minimal

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please show us the complete output without the edits.

Comment: I was happily using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS until today when I tried to upgrade my system using `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` and ended up with exactly the same issue. Did you get any solution for this?